# AWS Aurora migration during deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, amazon-aurora

I would like to make a step towards a no-downtime continuous deployment of my application. 
I have an app running on an EC2 instance that connects to the aurora database. During the deployment I need to run the database migration scripts and update the app running on EC2. How can I update both of them without causing any down time? I probably can configure Elastic Beanstalk/CodeDeploy to update the EC2 instance in such a way that for a while I will in fact have 2 instances of my app running on 2 separate EC2 instances, but that still gives me only one instance of the database. If I run my migration scripts, this may assassinate one of the instances of my application and if the deployment for some reason fails, I might not be able to revert the changes done to the database.

So basically the question is: what is the right way to apply the SQL migration scripts without causing any downtime?

Comment: Did you try aws dms ? https://aws.amazon.com/dms/free-dms/

Comment: nope. I thought it was for migrating from your premises to AWS, rather than migrating between different versions of the schema. Can it be used in that way as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on your specific situation and type of DB migration. One route you can follow, taken directly from AWS documentation is :

- [Clone your Aurora DB, using AWS provided API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html)
- Apply your migration script to the new DB
- [Deploy your new source code version to a new Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)
- Test your new source code with new DB
- Swap the two environment CNAME using the api provided by AWS or from your DNS, you may want to synchronize the data changes from old DB to new DB before doing so

Comment: Nice! I was scared that it will take forever to create a duplicate of the database and that it would completely DOS the production DB, but apparently it can be done in just a second. This will work. Thanks :)